# Adding only Distinct numbers during map reduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, bigdata

I have a csv as to which number called which number and the call details(duration and time etc.)

i want to have all the numbers a particular number called in an array.
that array should be an array of documents and so,in each document i can have all the call details also.
so finally i need documents with a "caller" number and a "called" array(that array is as defined above).

for this i had come up with a map reduce solution.(quite basic and intuitive).
but my problem is that i need only distinct numbers that a "caller" number has called.

my current mapreduce script repeats the dialled numbers.
how can i only consider unique numbers during the reduce phase?
my code looks like this:(i enter this in the mongo shell)

```
db.contacts.mapReduce(
  function(){
    numbers = [];
    value={phone:this.<<called_number>>};
    numbers.push(value);
    emit(this.<<caller_number>>,{called:numbers});
  },
  function(key,values) {
    result={called:[]};
    values.forEach(function (v) {
      var i,j;
      for(i=0;i<v.called.length;i++) {
        var flag=0;
        for(j=0;j<result.called.length;j++) {
          if(v.called[i].phone==result.called[j].phone){
            flag=1;
          }
        }
        if(flag==0) {
          result.called.push(v.called[i])
        }
      }
    });
    return result;
  },
  {"query": {},"out":"new_collection"}
)
```

I understand that the map and reduce functions are java script functions.
so even the javascript coders can help me out here(to create the reduce function).

Comment: Try http://mongobooster.com, a MongoDB GUI. You should at least format your code in the editor. Too hard to read.

Comment: how about now?please help me out

Comment: What are you try to do? Get all called number of same caller?

Comment: i want all the called numbers of 'a' caller number

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
db.contacts.mapReduce(function(){
     emit(this.<<caller_number>>, {called:this.<<called_number>>, callDuration:this.<<callDuration>>,...});}
    ,function(key,values)
      {
      var map = {};
      var called=values.filter(function removeDuplicated(it){
          if (!map[it.called]){
              map[it.called] = 1;
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      })
      return {caller:key, called:called};},
    {"query": {},"out":"new_collection"})
```

Comment: this is not what i wanted. a sample document after running the above code is like this: ```` { "_id" : NumberLong("99635*****")
, "value" : { "caller" : NumberLong("99635*****"),
 "called" : [ NumberLong("96183*****"),
 NumberLong("88971*****") ] } } what i want is the called array to be an array of documents.....(here it is array of numbers)....each element in the array should be a document because that doucment should contain the call details such as call duration,call time....etc